# Created table is not centered by bootstrap

Tags: java, css, twitter-bootstrap, jakarta-ee, jstl

In my project I am creating a dynamic table using jstl tags at run time and I am using bootstrap for responsiveness in my project.Problem is that my table created is not being limited in container element as if it has more  columns  for some search.

**Here is a snapshot of the problem:**

[image: Here is a snapshot of the problem :]

**My Code :**

```
 <div class="container" id="main">

// some code for adding menu 
<div class="row" id="featuresheading"> <!-- row for containg table  -->

   <div class="col-lg-12"> <!-- for col set -->


   <div class="table-responsive">
           <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">


             <tr>
             <c:forEach var="rna" items="${requestScope.searched_micro_rnas}">
                    <th >
                        <c:out value="${rna}"></c:out> 
                     </th>   

             </c:forEach>   
             </tr>        


              <c:forEach var="result" items="${requestScope.result_list}">

               <tr>
                 <c:forEach var="intval" items="${result}">



                         <td>
                         <c:out value="${intval}"></c:out>
                         </td>


                 </c:forEach>
               </tr>
             </c:forEach>

          </table>   
          </div> <!--  table responsive div ends -->

        </div> <!--  column div ends  -->
       </div> <!--  row ends -->
      </div><!--  container ends -->
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Wrap all of it in new style with overflow:auto and put the webkit scroll css on that div. Make a bootply

Answer (score 1):

can easily make responsive by assigning "col-*-*" classes to the "td" itself then your table become responsive.

Comment: I modified code by : <td class="col--"> ,but that did't work :(

Comment: Sorry . I have never used fiddle.